# Are there generic enchanted implements in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment

Looking through the alphabetical list of magic items (DMG p150) I see it includes:

- Ammunition, +1, +2, or +3
- Armor, +1, +2, or +3
- Weapon, +1, +2, or +3

But there don't appear to be any generic spellcasting implements. I had expected perhaps a "Holy Symbol, +1..." or even "Implement, +1...". There is the occasional *specific* wand, rod, etc. but most are of the "finite charges" variety, and are only really for the more wizardy kind of spellcaster.

Does 5th edition have generic spellcasting implements that provide a bonus to the attack (or saving throw DC) made with that implement? Does it have any holy symbols or totems that include this? If not, would homebrewing such a thing have a significant effect on balance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sort of.

The DMG includes some magic items along these lines. For example, on page 197 there is the *Rod of the Pact Keeper*, which can be +1, +2, or +3 and raises warlock spell attack and spell save DCs by that amount. Another one is the *Wand of the War Mage* on page 212, which only affects spell attack. Note that both of these have an additional minor benefit.

However, there are no generic items of this type like the +1, +2, or +3 Weapon or Armour.

As for whether homebrewing something like this would significantly impact balance, the answer is probably not. Given that there are existing magic items with these effects, it's simply a question of how rare an item of this kind should be. Both of the examples I gave above are uncommon if they are +1, rare if they are +2, and very rare if they are +3, just like the generic +X weapons. So generic spellcasting foci (note: in 5e they are foci, not implements) shouldn't be a problem.