# How does the 5th edition handle enhanced magic focuses

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I am currently using a Wizard and I just got my hands on a +4 dagger. More specifically the Rabbit Slayer from Dragonlance (ed.: a 2e item).

Question 1: According to official rules can it be used as a spellcasting focus

Question 2: If so how do I go about casting with a +4 focus in terms of modifiers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there generic enchanted implements in D&D 5e?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55077/are-there-generic-enchanted-implements-in-dd-5e)

Answer (score 19):

**No magic items above +3 exist in 5th edition**

By design magic weapons and items can only add up to +3 at maximum within the system's bounded accuracy. I've searched through the whole of the DMG treasure section and even legendary weapons only have a +3.

Wizards can use *Arcane Focus* items as an *Arcane Focus*

They are defined as:

> **Arcane Focus**. An arcane focus is a special item—
>   an orb, a crystal, a rod, a specially constructed staff,
>   a wand-like length of wood, or some similar item—
>   designed to channel the power of arcane spells. A
>   sorcerer, warlock, or wizard can use such an item as a
>   spellcasting focus, as described in chapter 10.

As such I would not deem daggers in general, nor weapon enchanted daggers as Arcane Foci.

Comment: Magic items with a +4 bonus *can* exist in 5e; the DMG section on creating magical items (page 285) features a table listing the highest bonus an item should give for each rarity level. +4 is listed as legendary rarity, which the DMG suggests characters generally won't get hold of until around 17th level. I'd imagine that for balance reasons, items should only give a +4 bonus if they don't do anything else, which is why the DMG items are all +3 or lower.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't handle enhanced magical foci. In order:

1. No, a normal dagger doesn't count as a spellcasting focus. (In theory a "dagger" specifically created to be a spellcasting focus could be made, but then it probably wouldn't function well as a dagger.)
2. Spellcasting foci only remove the need to use material components. They don't enhance spellcasting. In theory, a dedicated magic item to enhance spellcasting might exist, and it might double as a spellcasting focus, but that is not what a *dagger +4* does.

   If such a thing existed, the bonus would simply apply to your spell DC and your spell attacks.
3. You're in house-rule territory anyway, since magic items don't go as high as +4 in D&D 5e in the first place. Since you're in house-rule territory, any and all questions about this item can only *really* be answered by one person: Your DM.

---

Aside, and I know you didn't ask this at all: *Rabbitslayer* should probably be converted to fit with D&D 5e's math. If your DM wants to do that (and it's possible they don't — they might have a handle on whatever houseruling they're doing), then it's as easy as changing it from +4 to +3, since it has no other abilities that would need altering to fit. That simple change would keep it as a very-high bonus weapon in D&D 5e, as befits its status in AD&D 2e.

Comment: I just wanted to point out in the 5th Edition Dungeon Master's Guide there exist a magical item called the 'Rod of the Pact Keeper' , it's a magical +1, 2, or 3 'Rod' (Arcane Focus) that grants the Warlock bonuses to magic attack and saving rolls the enemy has to make based on it's +1-3 .  Sounds like a similar concept to what you're trying to brew up.

Comment: Not only that, there's also the "wand of the war mage", which works for all spellcasters. It grants them +1, +2, or +3 to spell attack rolls, and you ignore half cover. The Staff of the Magi is a quarterstaff that also gives you bonuses to spell attack rolls.

Comment: Yep. These are examples of the "in theory" I mentioned. I didn't want to get into them, because that's getting pretty far away from "can my dagger +4 do it?" and I didn't want the tangent (especially since it's *not* clear that they count as foci).

Answer (score 4):

**No official rule lists a dagger as a spellcasting focus.**

The various spellcasting foci are listed in the "Adventuring Gear" table (PH p.150):

- *Arcane focus*: crystal, orb, rod, staff, wand
- *Druidic focus*: sprig of mistletoe, totem, wooden staff, yew wand
- *Holy symbol*: amulet, emblem, reliquery

In addition, a Bard can use a musical instrument as a focus.

---

**The only enhanced magical foci in the official rules which you can use are the *Wand of the War Mage*, *Staff of the Magi*, or *Staff of Power***.

The *Wand of the War Mage* (DMG p.212) requires attunement by a spellcaster, and provides a bonus of as much as +3 to spell attack rolls.

The *Staff of the Magi* (DMG p.203) or *Staff of Power* (DMG p.202) require attunement by a Sorceror, Warlock, or Wizard, and provide a +2 bonus to spell attack rolls.

The best enhanced focus in the game at present is the *Rod of the Pact Keeper* (DMG p.197) which requires attunement by a Warlock, so your Wizard could only use this by multiclassing at least one level of Warlock.  It provides a bonus of as much as +3, both to spell attack rolls and to the saving throw DC of Warlock spells.

Comment: There's also the Staff of the Magi, which requires attunement by a wizard, sorcerer, or warlock.